# How to snapshot particular field angularfirestore2

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access particular field and get that field instead of whole data using angularfirestore2 snapshot or value changes

Here is the code

```
return this.angFirestore.collection(key).doc(id).snapshotChanges().map(data  {
       return data.map(d => {
         const id = d.payload.doc.id;
         return id;
       })
     })
```

I want this type of data `data = {id:1,like:3}` instead of`id:1,like:3,x:1, y:2....`